# Registrykey in 64 bits OS shows 32 bit applications

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, registry, registrykey

```
string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
```

gives me the same results as

```
string registry_key_x64 = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
```

both on a 64 bit OS. When i go in the Registry Editor and go to

```
"*SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*"
```

it shows me other applications then my code provides me.

For example in the Registery Editor i have "wampserver". [See picture of my Registry Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRfPS.png).

But when i run my code it shows different applications then i have in my Registry Editor ( it shows the 32 bit application list) [Command Prompt (Running Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Oa9J.png)

**My code :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
            {
                foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                    {
                        if (subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: See the [RegistryView Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your application runs as 32Bit application and therefore returns the WoW nodes of the registry. Build your application as AnyCPU or 64 Bit application.

Comment: I was running on AnyCPU, but i changed it to x64 and now it works thank you!